# Event handlers jQuery revisited

Tags: jquery, events

I have this code below:

```
$("#radar_play").click(function(){
console.log(this);
$(this).unbind('click');
$(this).bind('click');
....
.....
.....

}
```

Then in the `<body>` tag I have this button below

```
<button id="radar_play'">PLAY ANIMATION</button>
```

To me it looks like I am removing the click event(which does work)then re-attaching it.

But the click event never gets bound again. Anyone know why?

Comment: I meant to include <button id="radar_play">PLAY RADAR LOOP</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a handler when re-binding, you could name your closure and use it as follows:

```
$("#radar_play").click(function click_handler(){
   //Perform the onclick logic
   $(this).blabla...
   $(this).unbind('click');
   ....
   //now we want to bind again
   $(this).bind('click', click_handler);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are rebinding the click event you need to give it a **handler** too.. Otherwise the event will not be acted on..

```
 $(this).unbind('click');
    $(this).bind('click', function() {

        // What you want to do

    });
```

OR

```
$(this).unbind('click').bind('click', function() {

    // What you want to do
});
```

Also note that frequent bind and unbind is an **antipattern** .. You need to avoid it if you can